# calendar application on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, eventkit

```
NSPredicate *eventsForThisYear = [NSPredicate eventPredicateWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:[[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] calendars]];

NSArray *events = [eventDB eventsMatchingPredicate:eventsForThisYear];
```

In the following code I got an error saying 'CalCalendarStore' is undeclared (first use in this function)
In xcode 4.2. I did not find any `CalCalendarStore` Framework.

Comment: Is CalCalendarStore your own class? If so you need to import it in your class. If its part of a framework you will need to import the framework

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using *Calendar Store* framework which is unavailable on iOS. In iOS, you need to use [`EventKit`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

[`Here`](http://mobileorchard.com/ios-advanced-programming-event-kit-framework/)'s a tutorial. There are many others available online.